# Converting a string into TimeSpan

Tags: c#, asp.net, timespan

I have been playing around with the Google Distance Matrix API, so far I've been able to get duration strings in the following format

```
    string a = "1 days 5 hours";
    string b = "18 hours 10 minutes";
    string c = "29 minutes";
etc..
```

My question is how could I add all these strings together into a single `TimeSpan` variable?

Comment: Would TimeSpan.ToString() do the trick for you? see this link  

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx

Comment: How about writing some code?

Comment: @RameshRams that's going the wrong direction. He wants a TimeSpan.Parse()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#DistanceMatrixResponses
You should get a numeric value as well. (That would be seconds)

Comment: Thanks didn't see that, 
changed /DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/duration/text to value and worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can probably implement an [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) to pass into `TimeSpan.Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create only one TimeSpan values from each string mentioned above since the way TimeStamp work's in c# is:

```
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(1, 2, 0, 30, 0); //Days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.
```

The output will be

```
1.02:00:30
```

You can check MSDN for each type of input and parsing :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.timespan.aspx